# htaccss redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I just moved a site to a subdirectory. 
Instead of changing every link I'd like to do a 301 redirect via htaccess. Heres an example of what I want to do:
When someone tries to go to www.example.com/test.html, I want them really to go to www.example.com/website/test.html. 
When someone goes to www.example.com/documents/test.pdf, I want them to go to www.example.com/website/documents/test.pdf. 
I want to append the /website/ directory to every request basically. Because I moved the site from the root folder into this subdirectory.

I do have one restriction, I want to make it so that www.example.com/website1/ still goes to www.example.com/website1/. If this changes the solution please give me both solutions, because I am flexible with this.

Comment: They are 3 unique questions. The first was a redirect for all files/folders. The second was torubleshooting a redirection. This one is a redirect for all but one directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 basic approaches (there are some more, but they depend on your rewrite logic (other rules) so may not be suitable for every scenario):

**First:**

```
# Redirect all incoming requests into /website/ subfolder
# but excluding /website1/ folder
# First condition is to prevent infinite redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website1/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/website%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**Second:**

```
# Redirect all incoming requests into /website/ subfolder
# but excluding /website1/ folder
# Condition is to prevent infinite redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteRule ^(?!website1/).*$ http://www.example.com/website%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```